# Dynamic volume for keda ScaledJobs

Tags: kubernetes, keda

**Problem Statement:**
I am running keda ScaledJobs with azure-pipeline trigger, underlying node has low ephemeral storage so for each job I want to attach a volume that's available to the lifecycle of pod.

Job doesn't support creation of volume automatically.

Is there's any solution or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Kubernetes Volume Expansion as the node runs out of storage space, you may resize the volume to a desired size. The downside is that you need to restart the pods. Here is a documentation for guidance.[1]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#resizing-an-in-use-persistentvolumeclaim

Comment: you don't need to restart pods: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/